# How to filter specific value from KeyValue pipe to display under specific header in html table | Angular 6 +

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular6

Basically i have some JSON data (objects : Key value pairs) and i want to display it in html table ,so as i have only objects in my json i am using Keyvalue pipe, But the problem is i am getting all values from Keyvalue pipe randomly and displaying in table cell. i want to display specifically under respective headers.

I want to use data something like {{key1.value1}}, {{key2.value2}} ... so on.

My component.ts

```
products: string[];
```

constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) { }

ngOnInit() {

```
this.httpService.get('products.json').subscribe(
  data => {
    this.products = data as string[] ;


  },
  (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    console.log (err.message);
  });}}
```

My component.html

```
                          <table>
                          <thead>
                           <tr>

                              <th>Parameter</th>
                              <th>Order Val</th>
                              <th>Order Min</th>
                              <th>Order Max</th>
                          </tr>
                          </thead>

                     <tbody>
                     <tr *ngFor='let product of products | keyvalue'>
                        <td>{{product.value}}</td>

                           </tr>
                         </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Json data

{
  "parameter": "specimen",
  "orderVal": 2,
  "orderMin": 1,
  "orderMax": 6,
}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55849690/how-to-make-real-time-search-box-in-angular-7-cli-project/55849914#55849914

Comment: @arunkumar : Thanks for the reply, this question is completely related to new pipe (Keyvalue) which is introduced in Angular 6, I request you to please check again.

Comment: I think that is suitable only for map kind of fields

Answer (score 1):

One of the comments above correctly mentions that the keyvalue pipe is not intended for lists, but rather for map-kind fields (something with key & value pairs), so it is not applicable to `products: string[];`.

In Component.ts, instead of the list of strings (`products: string[];`), I would do a list of custom project objects (`products: myCustomProduct[];`), where `myCustomProduct` is a custom class (or you could use a type I suppose):

```
class myCustomProduct {
   parameter: string;
   orderVal: int;
   orderMin: int;
   orderMax: int;
}
```

Then in your `subscribe` statement in `ngOnInit()`, cast the JSON to `product`s (I'd have to see the full JSON to spell that out for you, not just a single product's JSON), which you can then use in HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor='let product of products'>
    <td>{{product.parameter}}</td>
    <td>{{product.orderVal}}</td>
    <td>{{product.orderMin}}</td>
    <td>{{product.orderMax}}</td>
</tr>
```

Although it may be attractive to try and encode each project as an unconstrained dictionary and then ngFor through the attributes automatically with a keyvaluepipe, this decouples the row from the hard-coded column headers in your example. Reading in the JSON as actual object models creates code that is more readable and maintainable, in my opinion.